# Building NodeJS module: linker library path in Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, dll, path, linker

I'm trying to port a NodeJS module to Windows (it works fine in Linux and FreeBSD). It requires a DLL to link. I've configured **npm** to use MSVS 2013. Module build fails with linker error (unresolved symbol).

I've tried adding the dll path to **binding.gyp**:

```
"ldflags": ["-LC:\my_dll_path", -lmy_lib]
```

or copying the dll (and the corresponding .lib) into MSVS 2013 lib directory - nothing helps.

Thanks for directions and ideas!

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate line in **bindings.gyp** will be the following:

```
"libraries": ["-lc:\\path\\to\my_stuff\\my_lib"]
```

where *my_lib* is the dll name without extension. The corresponding *.lib* file has to be at the same location.
Windows environment variables can be used in the path, e.g. **%appdata%**.